# How to use bootstrap datetimepicker to filter dates in bootstrap table?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-datetimepicker, bootstrap-table

I'm using WebAPI(JSON) in my tables and I need to filter the "dates" using datetimepicker in bootstrap-table. Pls. someone help me.

Note: Timestamp is the date need to filter

Table - this is to call WebApi in my tables

```
var WebApi = "http://track.asiacom.co.th/fmswebapi/api/posinfo";
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#report').bootstrapTable({
        idField: 'PosID',
        url: WebApi,
        columns: [{
            field: 'PosID',
            title: 'id',
            class: 'hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-desktop'
        }, {
            field: 'Asset',
            title: 'Vehicle'
        }, {
            field: 'Tag',
            title: 'Device'
        }, {
            field: 'Location',
            title: 'Location'
        }, {
            field: 'Timestamp',
            title: 'Timestamp',
            formatter: timestampFormatter
        }, {
            field: 'Battery',
            title: 'Battery'
        }, {
            field: 'Engine',
            title: 'Engine',
            formatter: engineFormatter
        }, {
            field: 'Ignition',
            title: 'Ignition',
            formatter: ignitionFormatter
        }]
    });
});
```

HTML - this is the datetimepicker form

```
<input id="dateFrom" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM">
<input id="dateFrom" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM"><br/>
<input id="dateTo" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM">
<small class="text-muted pull-left">To</small>
```

Javascript

```
$('#dateFrom').datetimepicker({
    format: 'dd-M-yyyy hh:ii:ss P',
    autoclose: 'true',
    todayBtn: 'true',
    todayHighlight: 'true',
    keyboardNavigation: 'true'
});

$('#dateTo').datetimepicker({
    format: 'dd-M-yyyy hh:ii:ss P',
    autoclose: 'true',
    todayBtn: 'true',
    todayHighlight: 'true',
    keyboardNavigation: 'true'
});
```

To Convert the date

```
function timestampFormatter(value, row) {
    var t = value;

    function convertUTCDateToLocalDate(date) {
        var newDate = new Date(date.getTime() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
        var offset = date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
        var hours = date.getHours();
        newDate.setHours(hours - offset);
        return newDate;
    }

    var date = convertUTCDateToLocalDate(new Date(t));
    var timestamp = moment(date.toLocaleString()).format("D-MMM-YYYY, hh:mm:ss A");
    return '<div>' + '<span><i class="fa fa-clock-o hidden-xs hidden-md"></i>&nbsp;' + timestamp + '</span>' + '</div>';
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what are you asking for.

Comment: You can read the title

Comment: But filter based on what criteria?

Comment: To filter the selected start and end date.

Answer (score 1):

```
format: 'dd-M-yyyy hh:ii:ss P',
```

check removing the format as dd-M-YYYY

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the Filter Control extension, here is an example:
jsfiddle.net/djhvscf/e3nk137y/1982/